# ALTER VIEW must be the only statement in batch

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I get this error message in SQL Server when I write the following ALTER VIEW statement. The ALTER VIEW line is underlined in red.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE name = 'SigHierarchyView')
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[SigHierarchyView] WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
(
SELECT    [Sig].[Id]
            ,[Sig].[UniqueId]
            ,[Sig].[TenantId] AS [ParentTenantId]
            ,[Sig].[Code_FR]
            ,[Sig].[Code_EN]
            ,[Sig].[DecodedText_FR]
            ,[Sig].[DecodedText_EN]
            ,[Sig].[DecodedText_ES]
            ,[Sig].[DecodedText_IT]
            ,[Sig].[DecodedText_VI]
            ,[Sig].[DecodedText_CH]
            ,[Sig].[Timestamp]
            ,[Sig].[Deleted]
            ,[Sig].[CreationDate]
            ,[Sig].[CreationUserUniqueId]
            ,[Sig].[ModificationDate]
            ,[Sig].[ModificationUserUniqueId]
            ,TenantHierarchy.[LeafTenantId] AS [TenantId]
        FROM dbo.[Sig]
        INNER JOIN dbo.TenantHierarchy ON  [Sig].TenantId = TenantHierarchy.ParentTenantId    
        WHERE  TenantHierarchy.Level = (
                    SELECT MIN(TenantHierachieIn.Level) 
                    FROM dbo.TenantHierarchy TenantHierachieIn               
                    INNER JOIN  dbo.[Sig] as SigIn  
                                ON SigIn.TenantId = TenantHierachieIn.ParentTenantId                            
                                AND SigIn.UniqueId = [Sig].UniqueId
                    WHERE TenantHierachieIn.[LeafTenantId] = TenantHierarchy.[LeafTenantId]
        )
)
```

GO

I tried putting a BEGIN and END but that didn't help. I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 6):

Batches in SQL Server are separated by the "GO" keyword. As you don't have any of those in your script, everything is in one batch. And, as you already found out, `alter view` needs to be in its own batch. One idiom that I like to use to protect against this is as follows:

```
if object_id('[dbo].[myView]') is not null --object exists
   set noexec on;
go
-- this will only get run if the object doesn't exist
create view [dbo].[myView]
as
   select 'stub' as message
go
set noexec off;
go
alter view [dbo].[myView]
as

-- actual view definition here
```

This way, I can use the scripting in SSMS to script out an `alter view` statement, throw the couple of lines of guard code on top of it, and I'm done.

Comment: Why all other objects can be created in a `BEGIN...END` clause but not views?! Microsoft is so consistent...

Comment: `BEGIN…END` signifies a module. You can put pretty much any logic you want inside of a module (including creating temp tables, using variables, etc). A view is pretty much restricted to a `select` statement, so that's why you don't bet `BEGIN…END` for it. "Consistent" != "works the way I'd expect it to"

Comment: This is actually a clever approach! I prefer this over execute statements as I can keep the code basically unaltered in SSMS and get intellisense.

Comment: These days, there is `create or alter` syntax for code-type things (views among them). If I'm on a version of SQL Server that supports that, I prefer that over the above. But if you're not… tada!

Answer (score 1):

ALTER VIEW will automatically overwrite the existing view. So you don't need the check first. But, for some reason, if you want to, SQL Server is telling you that a CREATE/ALTER view statement must be the first in a batch of statements. A batch can be separated by a GO. So what you can do is to drop the view first if it exists, in a batch, and then create the view in a new batch.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE name = 'SigHierarchyView')
   Drop View SigHierarchyView
GO

CREATE View...
```

Comment: So what's the purpose of having an ALTER VIEW statement if we always have to recreate it to modify it. I prefer not to recreate it because this is part of a large application with many developers and the security aspects of this view has to be recreated as well if I do this.

Comment: You don't always need to recreate it. You don't need to drop the view first. ALTER VIEW will overwrite the existing view definition. I simply thought you wanted to do it this way for some reason. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Are you using dacpac deployments?

Comment: @ChrisBint, no I'm not  using dacpac

Comment: Alternately, you could do `IF NOT EXISTS() CREATE VIEW` to create an empty stub, followed by the `ALTER VIEW`. That way you don't lose any permissions on the view by dropping it and re-creating it.